# LazyColumn does not fit to its contents in dialog

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a LazyColumn Inside a Dialog , inside a Simple Column which also contains a row of buttons (Cancel & Set) at the end of the dialog , Previously I was using weight(1f) modifier on the LazyColumn to occupy most of the height of the dialog then giving remaining space to the row of buttons but the problem is **weight modifier causes the list to expand full height even if its empty** and if I don't set weight modifier then **When the contents of the LazyColumn exceed LazyColumn starts occupying full height of the column** and the row of buttons cannot be found even upon scrolling.

I want to make it so that my row of buttons is aligned to the bottom of the dialog and LazyColumn takes as much height as its contents without taking space of row of buttons.

Here's my code

```
Column{
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)){
       items(myItems){ item->
          DisplayItem(item)
       }
    }
    Row{
       Button{}
       Button{}
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73733142/2624525

Comment: @Samad Great, Thanks for sharing, `fill=false` , I updated the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

You must use `fill = false` on the `weight` modifier on `LazyColumn` to fix this issue

[Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/73733142/2624525)

---

**Using AlertDialog**

```
AlertDialog(
    onDismissRequest = { /*TODO*/ },
    text = {
        LazyColumn{
            items(10){ num->
                Text(text = num.toString())
            }
        }
    },
    buttons = {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End) {
            Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                Text(text = "Cancel")
            }
            Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                Text(text = "Confirm")
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a modifier to your AlertDialog to limit the dialog height.
Row of buttons are visible.

```
AlertDialog(
    onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(.95f),
    buttons = {
        TextButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ } ) {
            Text(stringResource(id = android.R.string.ok))
        }
    },
    text = {
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            items(40){ num->
                Text(text = num.toString())
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: AlertDialog already works , no need to set the modifier , the other dialog doesn't work , try the code